# Excel count value

Tags: excel, count, countif

I am using Excel 2016, and I have sheet with Data as below

```
             January     February     March         April 
  Store 1     C                                      B
  Store 2                        
  Store 1                                            A
  Store 3
```

I need formula that count how many Store 1 has data in April. in this example it should be 2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. `=COUNTIFS(A2:A5,"Store 1",E2:E5,"<>")`